# When I rotate an imageview the size changes

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to essentially draw a line of width 10 from one spot on the screen to another (where the touch started and where the touch currently is) and I figured the best way to do that was to find the height and width and then rotate it to be in the right spot. Well I got it eventually but some weird things were happening and I don't know a ton about Swift so I'm hoping someone here has an explanation. Here is the relevant code

```
var touchBox: UIImageView!
var touchOrigin: CGPoint!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let position = touch?.location(in: self.view)

    touchOrigin = CGPoint(x: (position?.x)!, y: floors[fromFloor].image.frame.origin.y + 10)

    touchBox = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "lineImg"))
    touchBox.frame = CGRect(x: (position?.x)!, y: (position?.y)!, width: 20, height: 20)
    touchBox.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(touchBox)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let position = touch?.location(in: self.view)

    let x = min(touchOrigin!.x, (position?.x)!)
    let y = min(touchOrigin!.y, (position?.y)!)

    let w = max(touchOrigin!.x, (position?.x)!) - x
    let h = max(touchOrigin!.y, (position?.y)!) - y

    let angle = atan(h / w)

    touchBox.removeFromSuperview()
    touchBox = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "lineImg"))

    let hyp = sqrt(pow(h, 2) + pow(w, 2))

    // since it rotates around the center I have to find a new x, y
    let x1 = (2 * x + w) / 2
    let y1 = (2 * y + h) / 2 - (hyp / 2)

    touchBox.frame = CGRect(x: x1, y: y1, width: 10, height: hyp)

    // my image has arrows which is why I need to flip it sometimes
    if (touchOrigin!.y < (position?.y)!) {
        touchBox.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: -1, y: -1)
    }

    if ((touchOrigin!.x < (position?.x)!) == (touchOrigin!.y < (position?.y)!)) {
        touchBox.transform = touchBox.transform.rotated(by: -1 * (CGFloat(M_PI_2) - angle))
    } else {
        touchBox.transform = touchBox.transform.rotated(by: (CGFloat(M_PI_2) - angle))
    }

    touchBox.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(touchBox)

}
```

This version works the way I want it to. However, what is weird is that every time through touchesMoved I must redefine touchBox in order for it to work correctly. If I remove this (it has already been defined anyways) and the other lines that concern it (removeFromSuperview, alpha, addSubview), the width of the resulting image on the screen is way larger than 10 (and when I print the width I can confirm this). Alternatively, if I do this and remove the lines that rotate the image, it doesn't rotate obviously but the width does stay at 10.

I have tried rotating it with this instead

```
touchBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(M_PI_2) - angle))
```

but the same problem happens. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense to me, though. The "problem" of having a line drawn out to follow the user's finger is well-established, common, and previously solved, so I think you'd do better to search on it. You don't need any image view for this, and I think that that is just messing you up.

Comment: I do need an image view for a different reason later on which is why I am trying to solve it this way. Thank you though

Comment: I still think you're wrong, though. You might need an image view later, but then you can make an image view later, provided you still know how to _construct_ the image when you need it.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be you're over-thinking this? There's no need for an image view in order to do this, and replacing the image view on every `touchesMoved` call is just plain madness. This is just a self-drawing view that implements the three touches methods:

[image]

Comment: So if I did this, let's say I wanted it to be a line with arrows or a striped line or whatever as you draw, not a black line. Can I still do this? My goal isn't to replace the imageview but rather only change it's frame.

Comment: "My goal isn't to replace the imageview but rather only change it's frame" Well you _are_ replacing the image view. Your `touchesMoved` code says `touchBox.removeFromSuperview()` and `self.view.addSubview(touchBox)`. What do you think that does????

Comment: "So if I did this, let's say I wanted it to be a line with arrows or a striped line or whatever as you draw, not a black line. Can I still do this?" Sure, it's just more complicated. But if that is your goal, you asked your question in a rather foolish way, since you entirely concealed your real goal.

Comment: No no no no that's exactly what my question is. That is the only way I've been able to get it to work. I want to change the frame only but if I don't create a completely new imageview it doesn't work correctly. I know it is completely ridiculous to do this, hence my question.

Comment: (My question is more of a 'why doesn't this work?' than 'please tell me how to do it')

Comment: Well then my answer is not much use to you. I mean, I've shown you this is possible, and I've shown you it can be done without any image view at all, and if you don't like that, you don't like that.

Comment: When you reply to posts could you please be more helpful and less critical? I'm aware what I'm trying to accomplish can be done in other ways but I'm trying to understand why my original method was going so wrong and since I'm clearly not an expert in Swift (which is why I'm asking a question in the first place) I thought someone here could help. Thanks for answering

Comment: I'm not being critical. I'm sorry that my answer isn't helpful, that's all. It does seem to me to be doing exactly what you said you wanted done, but you are the judge. I have no problem with that.

Comment: If you read my original post you'll see I was looking for someone to tell me why I was wrong and not that I was wrong